# Modal verbs + be + past participle

Tags: modal-verbs

What does the "be generated" mean in this sentence.

> It should be generated directly to your account.

What does that mean?, is it a passive that it's generated by someone, or it means something else?. And how does the construction that being said work?.

I understand that the modal verbs + be + adjective but the past participle has confused me.

Comment: Yes, this is a _passive_ voice construction, and the epistemic modal _should_ expresses some, but not absolute, expectation of certainty about the future. You can read _should_ here as _is supposed to_ or _ought to:_ "It _ought to_ be generated directly to your account."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply the passive voice of the verb + should.  It isn't past tense  [More information on passive voice](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/activepassive.html)

> We generate the password (active verb, "to generate)
>
> The password is generated. (passive verb "to be generated")
>
> The password should be generated  (passive verb + should "should be generated")

Another example:

> I make the tiramisu.
>
> The tiramisu is made (by me).
>
> The tiramisu should be made.

Of course, this can all be past tense:

> I left the package.
>
> The package was left.
>
> The package should have been left.

Or future:

> He will forget the incident
>
> The incident will be forgotten
>
> The incident should be forgotten.

Or any other verb tense.  You just modify the "to be" verb. Note that "should" adds its own spin on the verb tense.  "Should" talks about future expectation, and "should have" talks about past expectation.  [More info](https://www.englishgrammarsecrets.com/shouldhave/menu.php)